# New to python and confused about get() returning None

Tags: python

So the task i am trying to accomplish is for two string inputs such as '1' + '2' to return '3',

I would like to be able to be able to do something like this,

```
d = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}
```

So i have a dictionary like this ^, then I can do

```
d.get('1')
```

In hopes it would return 1, except it returns None, How would I work around this?

### Thank you for the help

So thanks to your help i got it to work sort of, although for some reason it only accepts digits which add to 4 and lower, Here is the code so you may better understand

```
def code_char(char, key):
    d = {'1': 1, '2':2 ,'3': 3 ,'4': 4,'5': 5 ,'6': 6 ,'7': 7 ,'8' :8 ,'9':9}
    f = {1: '1', 2: '2' ,3: '3' ,4: '4' ,'5':5 ,'6':6 ,'7':7 ,'8':8 ,'9':9}
    sum = d.get(char)+d.get(key)
    if sum < 9:
        print(f.get(sum))
    else:
        sum = sum % 10
        value = f.get(sum)
        print(value)
code_char('1','5')
```

For some reason `code+char('1','3')` will correctly return 3 but any higher and it will just print None.

It's the start to my encrypter, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: The code in your question will return 1 actually.

Comment: This should work - can you show the interpreter output? Or the section of code where you do this?

Comment: Are you certain you have string keys? If you have integer keys instead, then yes, `.get('1')` will return None.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using `d.get(1)` instead of `d.get('1')`?

Comment: can you post the full section of code with output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why it returns None for you. Is that what you actually tried?

```
> d = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}
> d.get('1')
1
```

Btw, you can turn string to int by int function.

```
> int('1') + int('2')
3
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the silliness of this particular dictionary

Comment: Thanks for this, but would int('1') + int('2') return 3 as a int or as a string, as i need it to be returned as a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works: `D.get(k[,d=None]) -> D[k] if k in D else d`. Be sure to use '1' instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use braces:

```
>>> d = {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}
>>> d['1']+d['2']
3
```

Or, if you want a string result:

```
>>> str(d['1']+d['2'])
'3'
```

But really -- no mapping is required to do this:

```
>>> str(int('22')+int('33'))
'55'
```

Comment: ">>> str(int('22')+int('33'))
'55'" - this is what im looking for thank you all !